# Avoiding memory leak with circular references between classes

Tags: python, memory-leaks, weak-references

I am using a Python class that needs to keep track of callback functions/methods, and the instance of this class needs to have a reference (amongst other places) in one of the classes that provides a callback method. However, this is leading to a memory leak due to circular referencing of objects.

This is easier to explain in code:

```
import psutil
import numpy as np

process = psutil.Process()

def show_mem(title):
    mem = process.memory_info()
    print(title + ':')
    print('Real:    {0:.1f}Mb'.format(mem.rss / 1024**2))
    print('Virtual: {0:.1f}Mb'.format(mem.vms / 1024**2))
    print()

class CallbackTracker(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = []

    def add_callback(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)


class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.array = np.random.random(100000000)
        self.ct = CallbackTracker()
        self.ct.add_callback(self.callback)

    def callback(self):
        pass

def run():
    t = TestClass()

show_mem('Before run()')

run()

show_mem('After run()')
```

When run, this returns:

```
Before run():
Real:    22.4Mb
Virtual: 2451.9Mb

After run():
Real:    785.4Mb
Virtual: 3214.8Mb
```

The array is there to just make the memory usage more obvious. If I remove the following line:

```
        self.ct.add_callback(self.callback)
```

Then the memory leak goes away:

```
Before run():
Real:    22.3Mb
Virtual: 2451.9Mb

After run():
Real:    22.3Mb
Virtual: 2451.9Mb
```

What is the best way to avoid this? I have tried using weak references, but the issue is that the callback function appears to be dereferenced immediately after the class is instantiated:

```
import numpy as np
from weakref import proxy


class CallbackTracker(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = []

    def remove_callback(self, pcallback):
        print('removing callback')
        self.callbacks.remove(pcallback)

    def add_callback(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(proxy(callback, self.remove_callback))


class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.array = np.random.random(100000000)
        self.ct = CallbackTracker()
        self.ct.add_callback(self.callback)

    def callback(self):
        pass

t = TestClass()
print('done with TestClass()')
```

gives:

```
removing callback
done with TestClass()
```

which is no good because the callbacks (in the real code) would then not work. It's not clear to me why `self.callback` gets dereferenced before the end of the script. What is the best solution to my original problem, and is there a way to fix the weakref solution?

Comment: You can't create a weak reference to a method object, no, because nothing else will then reference the object anymore and it'll be cleaned up. You need something a little more permanent, like referencing the instance the method is bound to. See the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the duplicate question!